# Is 0-1 integer programming always NP-hard?

Tags: optimization, computational-complexity, integer-programming

I have the following problem.

Maximize $\sum\limits_{m=1}^M\sum\limits_{n=1}^N x_{mn}$

subject to: $\sum\limits_{\substack{m^\prime=1\\ m^\prime \neq m}}^M\sum\limits_{\substack{n^\prime=1\\ n^\prime \neq n}}^N \alpha_{mn^\prime}x_{m^\prime n^\prime} \leq \alpha_{mn},~~ \forall~ m\in\{1, 2, \cdots, M\}, \forall~ n\in\{1, 2, \cdots, N\} .$

where, $x_{mn} \in \{0, 1\}$, and $\alpha_{mn} \in \mathbb{R} ~\forall~ m\in\{1, 2, \cdots, M\}, \forall~ n\in\{1, 2, \cdots, N\}$

Please can I say that this is NP-hard problem using the fact that 0-1 integer programming is NP-hard? 
Is it related to knapsack problems? I know that the knapsack problem maximize the weights. For me all the weights are the same.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Of course not every 0-1 integer programming problem is NP-hard (unless P=NP, but in that case the concept of NP-hard is thoroughly uninteresting).  E.g. maximize $\sum_m x_m$ subject to $x_m \in \{0,1\}$ is a 0-1 integer program with a trivial solution.  A less trivial example would be maximum bipartite matching, which is easily represented as an integer program but is well-known to be polytime solvable.

Comment: @ErickWong Thank you. So if I want to say that a 0-1 integer programming problem is NP-hard, I have to prove it. I mean I cannot say that this problem is NP-hard because it is a 0-1 integer program.

Comment: Yup, you'll need to find an actual reduction from some existing NP-hard problem to this one.